# How Do i Secure My KML files for a rails application?

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

I would want to keep my KML files to be secure or password protected. I am keeping them on a public server, and i dont want them to be accessible to anyone.
I am using geoxml3, so any lock applied to the folder would not be a problem, because in this case google has no role to play.
I have tried using .htaccess but i guess the webrick server in rails does not support it.
Is there any other option?

Comment: KML has to be server on a public webserver, and google index them - your using the google maps api - the kml is parsed on google servers

Comment: But since i am using geoXML3, it is no longer parsed on the server. I want a way where in i don’t want these files to be accessible to any one using the url.

Comment: Store them in database and use php to mask the db source.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz,

But how do i store the entire KML files in the Database? Can you please elaborate? I am new to this, and i am not using php, its a rails app.

Comment: Vinit please read this Google Maps Official article - https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml

Comment: Mapperz, I did go through the link you sent me, but i guess i wont be able to store KML files in the Database. The KML files that i have are really complex, and apart from that i need to perform mouse-over event on the polygon object from the KML file. Something like [link](http://livelovely.com). And so i need a parser, like geoXML3.
But for the Parser to parse these files, they need to be present on the server it self. And since the server is public, the KML files would be accessible to anyone. I want a way to protect that folder, so that no one can access it by using the URL.

Comment: Lively are using PasteWSGIServer/0.5 Python/2.7.1+
and creating JSON from their database to do this which is a better option.

Comment: But i want to do the same thing using Rails. What are my options if database is not one? I just don't want those files to be accessed.